# MFC application with SQL Server - locking rows / table

Tags: c++, sql-server, mfc, locking

I want my C++ application (written in MFC + SQL Server) to behave in the following way:

1. Open an interface. It will read some data from a table and lock all the read rows, so that nobody else can change these rows, but can read them.
2. The rows from above paragraph are available to work with in the interface for a longer period of time, remaining locked for others until the interface is closed.
3. After some time (and a few of changes) I want to write the changes. The whole table should have an exclusive lock until the operation is complete. During this operation even reading from this table by others should be impossible (exclusive lock).
4. When the changes are written, the table should be unlocked (remove exclusive lock), but the rows mentioned in paragraph 1 should still remain locked, because I want to continue working on them.
5. At the end, close the interface (release the row locks).

The problem is that the above scenario will work only in a transaction started at the beginning. The table lock (TABLOCKX) will be held until this transaction will be committed or rollbacked, which is not what I want.

Any idea how to achieve this goal?

Comment: The described algorithm isn't ever going to work in a multi-user setup. Consider the following: User A locks a few rows, user B locks some other rows. Now user A is trying to commit some data, trying to get an exclusive lock on the DB, but can't, because user B still holds locks on its rows. You will have to go back and have another look at your requirements.

Comment: @IInspectable, I was afraid of this, but I was hoping there is some way to do it. Thanks for your reply.